# VoiceOver on iOS 14.2 says "funny things" when fancy styling an ordered list ol li elements (a11y)

Tags: css, ios, accessibility, html-lists, voiceover

follow code :

html :

```
<div class="list-container">
  <ol>
    <li value="1" class="list-element">
      car
    </li>
    <li aria-label="2" value="2" class="list-element">
      house
    </li>
    <li value="3" class="list-element">
      boat
    </li>

  </ol>

</div>
```

css :

```
.list-container .list-element {
  margin-bottom: 32px;
  color: blue;
}
ol {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: item;
  margin-left: 0;
}

ol li {
  counter-increment: item;
  font-family: FSAlbertBold;
  color: #222944;
  font-size: 20px;
}

ol li:before {
  margin-right: 10px;
  content: counter(item);
  background: #4682b4;
  max-height: 32px;
  max-width: 22px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: FSAlbertRegular;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

see and test in codepen https://codepen.io/iani/pen/VwKeKpq

safari on iOS 14 with Voice Over on announces when forward swiping over list :
"1 list start night sky", "car", "2 night sky", "house", "3 night sky", "boat"

hoped for result :
"1 list start", "car", "2", "house", "3", "boat"

semi solution :
was able to convince team to move to simpler styling, and use
'''li::marker''' as demo'ed here https://codepen.io/iani/pen/rNMxzgK
which is not supported in IE (as per https://caniuse.com/css-marker-pseudo)

Comment: Works fine in the provided fiddle on iOS 14 for me so tough one to help with. Are you **sure** it is saying "night sky" and not something else as maybe you have verbosity set high? The only other thing I could possibly think is that I don't have the "FSAlbertRegular" font and there could be something strange there. Hopefully someone else can replicate the issue.

Comment: some times sames "blue sky" ... does ocasionally work as expected but rarely

Comment: Can you set a completely different title and let us know what it sounds like?

Comment: i suspect these are CSS color names, and most likely a misreport of "Sky Blue" or "Midnight Blue". (See if changing the color values makes a difference). If so, I don't know why VO is reading these out - it doesn't do so on Mac - but it may something to do with content:counter(item) getting announced slightly wrong - perhaps a bug there. Can you confirm that you are using Safari?

Comment: yes, safari on iOS 14 (iPadOS)